# Async execution in org babel

Tags: org-babel, matlab

Is there a good general customization of org-babel to run asynchronously?
Recently I plan to use MATLAB via org-babel, but I would like it in an async manner, since some calculations do take time.

I do not wish to customize ob-matlab only. This is because I think it should be done in the level of framework instead of an application. In other words, a same modification should enable async feature for other language extensions e.g. R language.

Does anyone have a good solution?
So far I have tried `async.el` as well as `deferred.el` to modify `org-babel-execute-safely-maybe` that can be found in `ob-core.el` at the moment.

Comment: Another hint is can pass babel block to screen or tmux.

Comment: I've never implemented that, but it sounds possible. Thanks.

Comment: I guess I am accepting my own answer since there hasn't been any other solution posted for the last one month.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For future references and out-of-box libraries. I will accept this one for the answer because these are more recent.

#### ob-async

Here's a library using async.el
https://github.com/linktohack/ob-async

#### org-babel-eval-in-repl

My other solution (available in melpa):
https://github.com/diadochos/org-babel-eval-in-repl

Answer (score 7):

I have so far discovered that spawning a new Emacs process is a solution.

Here is what I have done.

#### 1. Add a function to start an external emacs process.

**init.el**

```
(defvar my/async-emacs-repl-org-babel-init-file "~/.emacs.d/org-babel-async-init" "File to load on executing async babel evaluation.")

(defun my/async-emacs-repl--start (process-name init-file)
  "Start a new Emacs process as a REPL server."
  (async-shell-command (concat
                        "TERM=vt200 emacs --batch -nw"
                        " --eval '(load \"" init-file "\")'"
                        " --eval '(while t (print (eval (read))))'"
                        )
                       process-name))

(defun my/async-emacs-repl--org-babel--start-server ()
  "Starts an Emacs process for async org-babel execution."
  (my/async-emacs-repl--start "*org-babel-async*" my/async-emacs-repl-org-babel-init-file))

(defun my/async-emacs-repl--org-babel--start-if-not-exists ()
  "Starts an Emacs process if the process does not exist."
  (if (not (get-buffer-process "*org-babel-async*")) (my/async-emacs-repl--org-babel--start-server)))

(defun my/async-emacs-repl--org-babel--execute--build-command (file-name line-number)
  "Build the command for executing `org-babel-execute-src-block'."
  (concat
   "(progn"
   " (find-file \"" file-name "\")"
   " (revert-buffer t t)"
   " (goto-line " (number-to-string line-number) ")"
   " (org-babel-execute-src-block t)"
   " (save-buffer)"
   ")"
   "\n"))

(defun my/async-emacs-repl--org-babel--execute (process-name file-name line-number)
  "Sends the command to the server to run the code-block the cursor is at."
  (process-send-string
   process-name
   (my/async-emacs-repl--org-babel--execute--build-command file-name line-number)))

(defun my/async-emacs-repl-org-babel-do-execute ()
  "Run org babel execution at point."
  (my/async-emacs-repl--org-babel--execute "*org-babel-async*" (buffer-file-name) (line-number-at-pos)))

(defun my/async-emacs-repl-org-babel-execute ()
  "Run by the user. Executes command. Starts buffer if not exists."
  (interactive)
  (save-buffer)
  (my/async-emacs-repl--org-babel--start-if-not-exists)
  (my/async-emacs-repl-org-babel-do-execute))
```

#### 2. Add a config file to load in the new emacs process.

The function above starts emacs in the `--batch` mode.
Thus the normal init.el will not be loaded.

Instead, we want to create a shorter configuration file (to load paths and so on).

The path to our new config file is stored in `async-emacs-repl-org-babel-init-file` in the snippet above.

**org-babel-async-init.el**

```
;; 1
(package-initialize)

;; 2
(setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil)

;; 3
(let ((my/org-babel-evaluated-languages
       '(emacs-lisp
         ditaa
         python
         ruby
         C
         matlab
         clojure
         sh
         dot
         plantuml)))
  (org-babel-do-load-languages
   'org-babel-load-languages
   (mapcar (lambda (lang)
             (cons lang t))
           my/org-babel-evaluated-languages)))
```

Here we ...

1. Add package paths.
2. Tell org-mode to not ask whether to execute code block.
3. Tell org-babel which languages are necessary.

Footnote 1: Without this setting, the evaluation will fail with `"No org-babel-execute function for $lang!"`

Footnote 2: Of course you can load the normal init.el instead of creating a new config file, if you wish. Do that by adding `(setq org-babel-async-init-file "~/.emacs.d/init")` to your `init.el`. But I think creating a configuration file for this task is more straightforward.

#### 3. Additionally...

Add to **init.el**

```
;; This will stop the new process buffer from getting focus.
(setq display-buffer-alist (append display-buffer-alist '(("*org-babel-async*" display-buffer-no-window))))

;; This will automatically show the result section.
(global-auto-revert-mode 1)
```

Add to **org-babel-async-init.el**

```
;; This will skip the "Save anyway?" confirmation of automatically saving the file when you also edited the buffer from Emacs while an asynchronous process is running.
(defun advice:verify-visited-file-modtime (orig-func &rest args) t)
(advice-add 'verify-visited-file-modtime :around 'advice:verify-visited-file-modtime)

;; This will skip the "Select coding system" prompt that appears when the result is inserted. This may vary among environments.
(setq coding-system-for-write 'utf-8)

;; This will skip the "changed on disk; really edit the buffer?" checking.
(defun ask-user-about-supersession-threat (fn) "blatantly ignore files that changed on disk")
```

Add to **org-babel-async-init.el** (you may not need these. These are for MATLAB)

```
;; This will set MATLAB cli path.
(setq-default matlab-shell-command "/Applications/MATLAB_R2016a.app/bin/matlab")
;; The MATLAB cli path can be obtained by running `fullfile(matlabroot, 'bin')` in your MATLAB.

;; This will stop MATLAB from showing the splash (the MATLAB logo) at the beginning.
(setq-default matlab-shell-command-switches '("-nodesktop" "-nosplash"))
```

Add to **org-babel-async-init.el** (you may not need these. These are for Julia, R and other languages that use ESS.)

```
;; This will enable :session header in Julia and other languages that use ESS (Emacs speaks statistics).
(load "/path/to/ess-site")
;; This will suppress ESS from prompting for session directory.
(setq ess-ask-for-ess-directory nil)
```

#### 4. Usage

(After the setup above.)

1. Move cursor to the code snippet you want to execute.
2. Run `M-x my/async-emacs-repl-org-babel-execute` (instead of doing `C-c C-c`). This will start an external Emacs process as a REPL server if needed, and then execute the source block you are at.

#### Acknowledgments

I have learned the idea of starting an emacs process for org-babel evaluation from [this post](http://www.draketo.de/english/emacs/parallel-babel). I would like to thank the author.

#### Comments for customization

The idea here is simple. Start a new emacs process as a REPL for Elisp, do `find-file` to the same .org file we are editing, `goto-line` to the same cursor point, run `org-babel-execute-src-block`, `save-buffer`. Stop exiting until the user stops the process (Otherwise, graphs would disappear immediately after they are shown).
One can naturally think about extending this by:

- Using org-mode's `C-c C-c` instead of running functions by hand / setting a new keybind (which can be achieved by advices).
- Conditionally switching process name according to :session variable and the language
- Conditionally switching init files based on the language.

In fact, the success of this approach seems to me to be showing a general way of developing async features in Emacs. Creating a "commands" layer, add scripts to do tasks, and have a framework for starting and reusing emacs processes. Just like Symfony framework of PHP (PHP doesn't have threads) has Command features.

#### Edit history

Refactored code (2016-04-02).
Solution now reuses an Emacs process (2016-04-02).
Solution now simplified and has only one `interactive` command to run (2016-04-02.
Added configuration (2016-04-12).

Comment: Have you seen [`async.el`](https://github.com/jwiegley/emacs-async)?

Comment: Yes, I have. It essentially starts a new process of Emacs, and runs the `lambda` function given to it. I didn't use it for this solution because I couldn't find a way to send data to the new process. Communicating the process is necessary if you want to use the :session feature of org-babel.

Comment: Thanks for working on this solution. I tried it but I get this error message: `TERM=vt200 emacs --batch -nw --eval '(load "~/.emacs.d/org-babel-async-init")' --eval '(while t (print (eval (read))))': exited abnormally with code 255.` Sorry, this should be a comment and not an answer, but I just don't have enough points.

Comment: After executing that, do you see a buffer named "*org-babel-async*"? If you can find one, that buffer probably contains more information about the error.
"exited abnormally with code 255" generally occurs when the program you wanted to run on the spawned emacs process failed. Possible ways out: 1) Check if you have the file specified in my/async-emacs-repl-org-babel-init-file. If you don't, create one as described above. 2) Check if you have listed the language you want to use in `org-babel-do-load-languages`. 3) The `#+SRC_BEGIN` block you are executing contains a bug.

Comment: Okay, so the issue was that I need to save my org file before running `M-x my/async-emacs-repl-org-babel-execute`, otherwise the "org-babel-async" buffer will complain: `...t/Dropbox/org/work.org locked by maarhart@htkl... (pid 68694): (s, q, p, ?)? 
Please type q, s, or p; or ? for help`. So if this can be solved, it would be fantastic. Thanks anyway for this, it is amazing! By the way, is it possible to bind it to `C-c C-c` or will it conflict with org-mode?

Comment: By the way, an extra parenthesis in the init.el block should be removed: "File to load on executing async babel evaluation.")

Comment: Oh, I see. Maybe you can make `my/async-emacs-repl-org-babel-execute` run `save-buffer` at the beginning. I have edited my answer to demonstrate this (see `my/async-emacs-repl-org-babel-execute` in `init.el`). Also removed the extra parenthesis. Thank you!
`C-c C-c` serves as an all-purpose key in org-mode (its function changes according to the context e.g. the cursor position). So you might not want to just override it (it's fine if you want to). Instead, I think there is a way to add a function to the `C-c C-c` family and let it run only under some conditions, which is more an organized way.

Comment: Thanks! But it is not that easy, because then you need revert-buffer or something like that, otherwise you don't see changes, and if you revert-buffer then typically your org-mode global state is set to OVERVIEW.

Comment: That is so true. I had forgot that I also use revert-buffer. (Unfortunately, as you have kindly figured out, this solution eventually relies on revert-buffer. The interaction between the main process and the spawned process is achieved through editing the org file. In order to implement a round-trip interaction between your emacs instance and the spawned process, one needs async.el or deferred.el.

Comment: Okay, I'm sure that if you could post a solution that required async.el or deferred.el, many org+Matlab users would be very thankful!

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear, but my point when I referred to async.el and deferred.el was that the solution would require building a whole framework for a round-trip interaction. That can be made easier with async.el and deferred.el, but unfortunately I don't have time to do that now. Still more comments are welcome, and if someone finds a solution like that somewhere in the vast sea of elisp, please do leave that as a comment.

Comment: In fact, on a second thought, I think that the interaction via editing and saving the file has an advantage over writing a round-trip interaction framework. It's that we can use the supported behavior of org-babel itself. Org mode does edit the buffer when it outputs the result. Thus I think letting Org-mode execute and edit the buffer as usual is more robust because we don't need to control the behavior of Org-mode that's running on another instance of emacs. (Still, I understand the problem that you have, @mhartm. Maybe what should be fixed is the behavior of Org-mode with revert-buffer.)